# Multiline truncation with ellipisis and wrapping

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to achieve the below design where the text wraps around a heading and truncates by ellipisis after the second line.

[image: Desired result]

---

I could achieve the truncation using flexbox and line clamping but am not able to wrap the text around the heading.

[image]

Snippet below:

```css
#container {
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
}
#header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#text {
  background-color: lightblue;

  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="header">Ad</span>
  <span id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</div>
```

---

I tried to use float, but, using  `display: -webkit-box;` makes the text behave like a block element and it does not wrap around the heading.

[image]

Snippet below:

```css
#container {
  max-width: 500px;
}
#header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  
  float: left;
}
#text {
  background-color: lightblue;

  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="header">Ad</span>
  <span id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</div>
```

---

Any pointers on how I could make the text truncate and also wrap around the heading? Thanks.

Comment: Your first example but with the `#header` span placed within the `#text` span would seem to solve the problem. Is this a possibility?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Both the header and text come from different services. So placing the header inside is not an option. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just moving the line-clamping to parent and letting children be inline?

```css
#container {
  max-width: 500px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
}

#header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#text {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="header">Ad</span>
  <span id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work! Why did I not think of before! Thanks a ton!